# Reboot frozen system

Tags: reboot, freeze, sysctl

Due to some reason, my machine is not responding and remains in frozen state.

- I am unable to ping it
- I am unable to use keyboard/mouse
- No script runs as per scheduled in cron
- Only way to use the system is to hard-boot it

Is there any way, maybe sysctl, to reboot the system on its own as soon as system is (or about to) entering into freeze mode.

I prefer to find the root cause and resolve it but unable to get reason. Hence knocking back door.

**EDIT_1:**

Is there any case where *H/W watchdog* fails to reboot the system ?

Comment: @StephenKitt No. Daemon is missing in system.

Comment: I am not sure about it. How do I check it ?

Comment: If you have a manual (for your system or your motherboard), it should mention it if there is one. If your system has a setup (BIOS or UEFI), there would normally be an option there to control the watchdog, if there is one; but in some cases the hardware has a watchdog without any mention in the setup. What kind of system is it?

Comment: I just verified on hardware and found nothing related to watchdog. Underlying board is Lenovo Thinkpad

Comment: It’s possible your Thinkpad has an AMT watchdog, but I’m not sure that can be configured to reboot the system. Regarding the general approach, see [this Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/64057/86440).

Comment: `dmesg | grep -i watchdog` gives following output
[    0.013281] NMI watchdog: Enabled. Permanently consumes one hw-PMU counter.
[    7.437287] sp5100_tco: SP5100/SB800 TCO WatchDog Timer Driver v0.05 [ 1745.077590] iTCO_wdt: Intel TCO WatchDog Timer Driver v1.11

Comment: You might be able to use the magic SysRq key to reboot (if your kernel supports it). Hold `[ALT]` and `[SysRq]`, then type `reisub`.

Comment: I am unable to use keyboard as it is not responding.